# Отправка данных формы html на почту без Outlook

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так чтобы данные из формы отправлялись на почту без помощи Outlook.

```html
<div class="form">
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="telephone" id="phone1" alt="Your phone" placeholder="Your phone">
    </br>
    <input type="name" name="username" id="nameuser" alt="Your name" placeholder="Your name">
    </br>
    <input type="submit" name="Send" value="Send" id="button">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Функция `mail()` в `php`?

Comment: @NTP Подскажите, пожалуйста, как её использовать

Comment: Если пользуетесь pdo или mysqli то используйте функцию sendmail,если используете ниже версию php 5.6 и т.д то используйте mail().Мануал прочитайте в гугле.Главное не забывайте о заголовках sendmail или mail.Могу скинуть код в вк если там есть вы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужна функция `mail()`, вот простой пример использования:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Больше в официальной [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php)

В вашем случае это будет что-то в виде:

```
<div class="form">
  <form action="send.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="telephone" id="phone1" alt="Your phone" placeholder="Your phone">
    </br>
    <input type="name" name="username" id="nameuser" alt="Your name" placeholder="Your name">
    </br>
    <input type="submit" name="Send" value="Send" id="button">
  </form>
</div>
```

И в `PHP` получайте данные и вставляйте в письмо:

```
<?php
    $phone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
 ?>
```

Comment: спасибо, очень помогли!